# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type A

Tags: javascript, typescript

Type `A` in the question is referring to in this example `BadgeTypes` type
and full error is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type A.No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type A
```

Sandbox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-type-checking-question-hkfmc
(NOTE: But for some reason it did not show the error -_-)

I am having problem come out a proper fix. and all the sorta relevant posts are going over my head. Would appreciate an answer accompany with explanations

```js
type BadgeTypes = {
  success: string;
  secondary: string;
  alert: string;
  text: string;
};

type Theme = {
  fonts?: object;
  borderRadius?: string;
  primary?: object;
  accent?: object;
  action?: object;
  stories?: object;
  checkbox?: object;
  badge: BadgeTypes;
  button?: object;
  page?: object;
  states?: object;
  modal?: object;
};
interface Props {
  theme: Theme;
  large: boolean;
  type: keyof BadgeTypes;
}
const StyledBadge = styled.span<Props>`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: ${(props: Props) => props.theme.borderRadius};
  text-align: center;
  color: ${(props: Props) => props.theme.badge.text};
  font-size: ${(props: Props) => (props.large ? `1.4rem` : `1rem`)};
  padding: ${(props: Props) =>
    props.large ? `0 .8rem` : `0.2rem 0.6rem 0.3rem 0.6rem`};

  // error happens here
  background: ${(props: Props) => props.theme.badge[`${props.type}`]};
`;
```

Comment: Please post actual code text instead of images, as mentioned in [ask].  Ideally such code should also constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate your issue.  The easier you make it for others to test out the problem for themselves, the higher your chances of getting a useful answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to index `badge`.

Basically:

```js
// this is a string
let x = `${props.type}`;

// this is "success" | "secondary" | "alert" | "text"
let y = props.type;
```

If you write `props.theme.badge[props.type]` the type checker should be happy.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWW! lol never thought about that! Thanks

Comment: The simple stuff is always the easiest to miss :)